# Is it able to debug my android application on my friend's android phone via internet?

Tags: android, debugging

My android application works well in my phone. I sent it to my friend and it crashes on my friend's phone, but I can't get the error logs.

Is it able to deploy my application direct to my friend's phone via internet? That I can see the error messages via logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ACRA](https://github.com/KevinGaudin/acra) may help you here.  It would allow you to gather the error reports from remote users of your application.